# How do I make the button work when I enter "1" in the textField?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jtextfield

```
public MultiplicationTable()
{
    JLabel jl;
    JTextField tf;
    JButton btn[];
    Container c;
    JPanel p1, p2, p3;
    int a;
    String value;

    super ("Multiplication Table");
    c = getContentPane();
    p3 = new JPanel (new FlowLayout());
    btn = new JButton[1];
    btn[0] = new JButton ("Show Times Table");
    jl = new JLabel ("Enter a Number:");
    tf = new JTextField(5);
    p3 = new JPanel (new BorderLayout(5,5));
    p3.add (jl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    p3.add (tf, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    p3.add (btn[0], BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    btn[0].addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                String Value;
                Value = tf.getText();
                if (Value == "1")
                {
                    System.out.print ("asd");
                }
            }
        }
    );

}
```

I would like to make the action listener for the button as I enter "1" in the text field. I really need to work on these codes. I wish you could help. Thanks!

Comment: Why not add an `ActonListener` to the text field?  It will fire when the user presses the enter key.  To know when the text in the field changes, add a `DocumentListener`..

Comment: `if (Value == "1")` 1) `Value` should be `value` (to meet Java naming conventions). 2) `== "1"` should be `.equals("1")` for correct string comparison.

Comment: See this [`if (Value == "1")`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `==` is testing whether the two strings are the same object.

Remember this:

`==`        tests for reference equality

`.equals()` tests for value equality

If you want to know if two strings have the same value you should use `.equals()`, (as was already pointed out).

Also, as a Java naming convention, for variable names use lowercase for the first word and capitalize only the first letter of each of the remaining words.